# Bind font symbol from database in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, sybase

I'm having buttons in a WPF project that have Segoe UI Symbols as their content. This works when I set the symbol in XAML directly or when I define the symbol in C# and bind it in the XAML. When I get the symbol from the database and bind it in the XAML, I always get the explicit value instead of the symbol:

```
<!-- Directly in XAML: works -->
<TextBlock Text="&#xE10F;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"></TextBlock>

<!-- Define in C# (Icon = "\uE10F") and bind in XAML: works -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Icon}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"></TextBlock>

<!-- Getting any of these values from the database: doesn't work 
     &#xE10F;
     &amp;#xE10F;
     \uE10F
     \\uE10F
-->
```

Would this be a database (Sybase) issue or is there a way to solve this in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by converting the icon in my ViewModel using

```
icon.Icon = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(icon.Icon);
```

This converts the icon (stored as a string in the database) to a Unicode character.